# Pine v5 How to Delete Certain Labels?

Tags: pine-script

This script plots Nadaraya-Watson excursions outside a channel (envelope). Nadaraya-Watson is a type of Kernel regression method that makes use of the Gaussian kernel as a weighting function. Unlike a regular moving average whose degree of smoothness is commonly determined by the length of its calculation window, the degree of smoothness of the NW envelope is determined by the bandwidth setting, with a higher value bandwidth returning smoother results. The indicator as scripted plots when a bar extends above or below the upper and lower boundaries of the envelope. It is not unlike a Bollinger or Keltner envelope, but with a different calculation basis. The script does work as is. If you put it on any price chart you will see the "excursion" points indicated by "S" and "B". The reason I posted on StackOverflow is because I don't know how to delete older plots of the "excursions". In other words, the chart can get quite cluttered with lower bandwidth settings and difficult to see the price bars. Ideally, I would like the plot to only show the most recent 3 or 4 "excursions". Can you help?

```
//@version=5
indicator("NW-OB/OS-hl2-BW(3)-multi(1)", overlay = true, max_lines_count = 500, max_labels_count = 500, max_bars_back=500)
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Settings
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
h = input.float(3.,'Bandwidth', minval = 0)
mult = input.float(1, minval = 0)
src = input(hl2, 'Source')


repaint = input(true, 'Repainting Smoothing', tooltip = 'Repainting is an effect where the indicators historical output is subject to change over time. Disabling repainting will cause the indicator to output the endpoints of the calculations')

//Style
upCss = input.color(color.new(color.blue, 100), 'Colors', inline = 'inline1', group = 'Style')
dnCss = input.color(color.new(color.blue, 100), '', inline = 'inline1', group = 'Style')

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//Functions
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
//Gaussian window
gauss(x, h) => math.exp(-(math.pow(x, 2)/(h * h * 2)))

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//Append lines
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
n = bar_index

var ln = array.new_line(0) 

if barstate.isfirst and repaint
    for i = 0 to 499
        array.push(ln,line.new(na,na,na,na))

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//End point method
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
var coefs = array.new_float(0)
var den = 0.

if barstate.isfirst and not repaint
    for i = 0 to 499
        w = gauss(i, h)
        coefs.push(w)

    den := coefs.sum()

out = 0.
if not repaint
    for i = 0 to 499
        out += src[i] * coefs.get(i)
out /= den
mae = ta.sma(math.abs(src - out), 499) * mult

upper = out + mae
lower = out - mae
 
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//Compute and display NWE
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
float y2 = na
float y1 = na

nwe = array.new<float>(0)
if barstate.islast and repaint
    sae = 0.
    //Compute and set NWE point 
    for i = 0 to math.min(499,n - 1)
        sum = 0.
        sumw = 0.
        //Compute weighted mean 
        for j = 0 to math.min(499,n - 1)
            w = gauss(i - j, h)
            sum += src[j] * w
            sumw += w

        y2 := sum / sumw
        sae += math.abs(src[i] - y2)
        nwe.push(y2)
    
    sae := sae / math.min(499,n - 1) * mult
    for i = 0 to math.min(499,n - 1)
        if i%2
            line.new(n-i+1, y1 + sae, n-i, nwe.get(i) + sae, color = upCss, style=line.style_solid, width = 1)
            line.new(n-i+1, y1 - sae, n-i, nwe.get(i) - sae, color = dnCss, style=line.style_solid, width = 1)
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  width
               
            
        if src[i] > nwe.get(i) + sae and src[i+1] < nwe.get(i) + sae
            label_red = label.new(n-i, src[i], 'S', color = color(na), style = label.style_label_down, size=size.huge, textcolor=color.new(color.red, 0), textalign=text.align_center)
            label.delete(label_red[2])


        if src[i] < nwe.get(i) - sae and src[i+1] > nwe.get(i) - sae
            label_green = label.new(n-i, src[i], 'B', color = color(na), style = label.style_label_up, size=size.huge, textcolor = color.new(color.green, 0), textalign = text.align_center)
            label.delete(label_green[2])

        y1 :=  nwe.get(i)

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: I know how to delete ALL labels (see below).. Is there a way to delete all but the most recent 5 labels for example?

label.new(bar_index, close)

a_allLabels = label.all

if array.size(a_allLabels) > 0

    for i = 0 to array.size(a_allLabels) - 1

        label.delete(array.get(a_allLabels, i))

Answer (score 0):

Push your `label`s into an array. Then check its size. Whenever it is greater than 5, you can use the `array.shift` to remove the first element and get its value which will point to the oldest `label`. Then delete it.

```
var label_arr = array.new_label()

len_arr = array.size(label_arr)

if (len_arr > 5)
    lbl = array.shift(label_arr)
    label.delete(lbl)
```

Comment: Hi Vitruvius - Thanks for the attempt but I added the lines into the script and it made no change. Did you try adding script to a chart and see if your addendum made a difference?

Comment: Yes. Are you pushing your labels into the array?

Comment: I'm stuck. I don't know where to insert the array.push (probably in two places one each for the up labels and the down labels). I don't know how to call the labels into the array.shift function.

Comment: I'm fine with you completing this and taking credit for the script if you want to. I just want to get the end result of an uncluttered chart.